# ASP.NET - Aplicação com possibilidade de autenticação Forms e Windows

Tags: asp.net, webforms, iis, autenticação

Tenho que configurar o seguinte cenário de autenticação ASP.NET: dependendo de algumas condições preciso que a autenticação seja realizada através de Forms ou Windows.

O cenário é o seguinte se for identificado um usuário autenticado, a autenticação da aplicação deverá validar o Login no AD(Active Directory), no caso de uma intranet por exemplo. Caso o acesso tenha sido feito através da internet, a autenticação da aplicação deverá ser realizada através de Forms, solicitando as credenciais cadastradas em base de dados associadas ao usuário.

Pelo que vi até o momento o ASP.NET permite na aplicação uma ou outra autenticação, até porque a mesma depende de configurações no IIS. Alguém já precisou configurar esse cenário, e pode me auxiliar nesse sentido?

Comment: Vai ter de fazer manual. Verifique se está logado no domínio (por exemplo verificando `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity`) e se não estiver, direcione para uma página que solicite as credencias e autentique o usuário.

Comment: Em ambos casos a autenticação será validada pelo AD... A diferença é que no acesso via rede interna esse usuário já está logado no domínio...

Comment: @RicardoPontual, mas eu terei que manter as configurações para autenticação Windows do lado da aplicação, bem como no IIS?


Web.Config
  
<identity impersonate="true"/>
<authentication mode="Windows">
<forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name=".ASPFORMSAUTHLC" protection="All" timeout="20" slidingExpiration="true"></forms>
</authentication>

IIS

Asp.NET Impersonation = Enabled
Windows Authentication = Enabled

Comment: @LeandroAngelo por favor leia o texto da pergunta: *"Caso o acesso tenha sido feito através da internet, a autenticação da aplicação deverá ser realizada através de Forms, solicitando as credenciais cadastradas em base de dados associadas ao usuário."*